# Could not resolve artifact / missing artifact (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

When importing a maven Android project into eclipse I get the following error:

```
Could not update project assistance configuration
  me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.configuration.ProjectConfigurationException: 
  org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact android:android:pom:2.1_r2
```

In the Package Explorer I have an error in the pom.xml files in "MyProject" and "MyProject-it" that says:

```
Missing artifact android:android:pom:2.1_r2
```

I have cloned the Maven Android SDK Deployer to my drive and run the "mvn install" command from the root of this folder, and it ran with success for the API I need. 
I have confirmed in the Android SDK manager that all relevant APIs are installed and that paths for JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME and M2_HOME are correct, but I still get this error.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware btw.

Can anyone help / point me in any direction?

Comment: Please post an answer with the solution instead of editing the answer into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I found:

I found out that I had to change the `<version>` tag in the parent pom.xml file from `2.1_r2` to `2.1_r3`. That solved my problem.